# Is it possible to use variables in the terminal mount point within the yml itself?

Tags: yaml, github-actions

Suppose I have a piece of yml that looks like this:

```
  - name: Upload data as artifact
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
    with:
      name: ssql-data
      path: training-data.csv
```

This is a step within a job that is using ubuntu. The job has some global variables, e.g. $TRAINING_DATE which has values such as '2021-01-01'.

Is there some way to use this variable within the yml itself e.g.

```
  - name: Upload data as artifact
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
    with:
      name: $TRAINING_DATE + "-" + "ssql-data"
      path: training-data.csv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, but please use `env` context

```yaml
- name: Upload data as artifact
  uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
  with:
    name: ${{ env.TRAINING_DATE }} + "-" + "ssql-data"
    path: training-data.csv
```

Comment: This is great! I didn't actually think this was going to be possible - sincere thank you